# Importing other groovy scripts -- getting errors

Tags: groovy

I am trying to build a groovy class that holds common methods. Getting this error and not sure how to fix

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Compilation incomplete: expected to find the class pages.manage.Common in file:/Users/jsmithers/groovy/Development/groovy/automation/qa-automation/pages/manage/Common.groovy, but the file contains the classes: Common
```

Here is the import line in my other script

```
import pages.manage.*
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Try removing semicolon where you have defined package "pages.manage", for me it worked after that, otherwise I also encountered with the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to specify the package in the script you are including, like 'package pages.manage'.